# Laravel - How do update a table immediately records are saved in it

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `appraisal_goal_types` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `max_score` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then I created this controller to store record in another table.

```
public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{  
    $appraisalStartDate = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_start_date);
    $appraisalEndDate = Carbon::parse($request->appraisal_end_date);        
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    try {
        $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $request->appraisal_identity_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;   //$request->employees_id
        $goal->weighted_score           = $request->weighted_score;
        $goal->goal_title               = $request->goal_title;
        $goal->goal_description         = $request->goal_description;
        $goal->company_id               = Auth::user()->company_id;
        $goal->created_by               = Auth::user()->id;
        $goal->created_at               = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $goal->is_active                = 1;

        if ($request->appraisal_doc != "") {
            $appraisal_doc = $request->file('appraisal_doc');
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $appraisal_doc->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $appraisal_doc->move(public_path('storage/documents/appraisal_goal'), $new_name);
            $goal->appraisal_doc = $new_name;
        }                      
        $goal->save();    
        $parentids = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->whereNotNull('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id', $goal->goal_type_id)->first();
        $parentid = $parentids->id;
        $goal->update(['parent_id' => $parentid]);  
}
```

As soon as the record is saved, I want to quickly query appraisal_goal_types

```
$parentids = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->whereNotNull('parent_id')->where('id', $goal->goal_type_id)->first();
$parentid = $parentids->id;
$goal->update(['parent_id' => $parentid]);
```

and update the record.

I need only one row there where the answer is true. I used the code above, but nothing is happening.

How do I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Why don't get `parent_id` before you insert the goal ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
$parentids = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->whereNotNull('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id', $goal->goal_type_id)->first();
    $parentid = $parentids->id;
    $goal->parent_id = $parentid;
    $goal->save();
```

There is an another solution like this,

```
$parentids = DB::table('appraisal_goal_types')->select('parent_id')->whereNotNull('parent_id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('id', $goal->goal_type_id)->first();
$parentid = $parentids->id;
AppraisalGoal::where('id', $goal->id)->update(['parent_id' => $parentid]);
```

Both will works. And let me know if you solved the issue